# Adding Launchscreen Xib to an older app changes appearance?

Tags: ios, xib

This question is in line with [Removing LaunchScreen messes up the looks of the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936633/removing-launchscreen-messes-up-the-looks-of-the-app)
But it is not the same. I have a legacy app which uses default.png images for the splash screen. As a part of the upgrade, I added LaunchScreen xib file (Application uses xib). I did add it in launch screen general tab.
Now the issue is after adding the launch screen all my views are zoomed out and everything appears a bit small. Why so?

Comment: show some UI....

Comment: **In your Project please check required splash-screen Default-568h@2x.png (640 × 1136 pixels) and clean project and run again**

Comment: I want to use launch screen

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom